# how to change eclipse jdk version used by default (1.5)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm using eclipse endigo, I configure it to use jdk 1.6, by when ever I do a maven update, the JRE version become 1.5, I see some question discussing the same issue and I tried the solutions but they doesn't work for me :

- I added the -vm param pointing to the desired javaw version  in my eclipse.in (doesn't work)
- I configured the Installed jdk in java preferences (doesn't work)
- I specify the desired java version in preference->java->compiler (doesn't work), I even define a specific conf for each project (doesn't work)
- define the **"mvn-compiler-plugin dependecy"** **works** by I'm working on an existing project and I don't want to change the pom.

Is there anyway to change this behavior.

Comment: IMHO, the point of changing the `maven-compiler-dependency` is actually a good practice, as you can be sure of the version compliance for your project, and it won't get any conflicts with your team working on the project.

Comment: thx for responding, and yeah it's true what did you say, but I wonder if there is an other way

Comment: Maven defaults to 1.5 which is why you are getting this behaviour. Your repository should handle what JDK it requires. it is not the job of the IDE. You should update the POM and set the compiler target/source settings.